# How to tell what page an image belongs to in PDF specification?

Tags: php, image, pdf, low-level

I'm doing some low-level extracting of images directly out of a PDF file with PHP, since GhostScript is too slow, and I'm doing pretty well. But the problem is that I can't figure out where it says which page an image belongs to. I have no problem getting the images out of the PDF, but I'm having trouble figuring out the order of them.

Where in the PDF data does it say what page an image is supposed to be displayed on?

Comment: if u could share what ur doing in detail we can help

Comment: I'm extracting images from a PDF... open a PDF with Notepad++ and you'll see what it looks like.

Comment: search for page breaks but what ur doing may not be right

Comment: Would you mind to share your (now working) PHP script for this?

Comment: It don't think it'll work on anyone else's machine, it requires the system to have jbig2dec and exactimage installed in order to read the images, which are uncommon applications and have to be installed from source on the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Images are stored in a PDF as standalone objects. They are referenced from a page through the page's Resources dictionary, XObject subdictionary. The relation is page -> resources -> images, so in order to know to what page an image belongs to you have to scan all the resource dictionaries of all the pages and see in which resources dictionary your image appears. An image can be referenced from multiple resource dictionaries. This is very low level PDF manipulation, I do not know how low level are you working in your code.

Comment: Got it. So the page object references the resources object, which references the xobjects object, which references the image. Could you please now answer me this: where does it say what position on the page the image is placed?

Comment: In order to know the position of the image on the page you have to parse and execute the page content stream. The image is painted on the page using the Do operator, its operand being the image id in the resources dictionary. The position and size of the image on the page are determined by the current transformation matrix that is in place when the Do operator is executed.

Comment: There are also 'inline' images, where the image data is stored directly in the page Contents stream rather than as an XObject. Just so you're aware that not all images are XObjects!

Comment: KenS is right.Inline images are identified in the content stream by the BI/EI tags. Their position and size is determined the same way like standard XObjects.

Comment: Cool. I have it all working now. The script can recognize and follow endless annoying "redirects" or the inline format, it grabs all the images, page sizes, image placement and sizes, etc. Only thing that will crash it is if there are mutliple catalog (root) objects... does that ever happen?

Comment: Yes, there can be multiple catalog objects but only the last one is valid. This situation appears when saving a file in incremental mode, this mode appends the changed objects at the end of the source PDF file. You have multiple versions of a PDF object (document catalog, page, etc) and only the last version should be considered.